# What is the appropriate way to communicate with Google API from Spring back-end?

Tags: java, spring, api, backend, google-translate

I am trying to create a translator from angular using Spring. So in Spring I created this end point

```
package com.vir.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.vir.exception.ApiError;
import com.vir.model.iTranslator;
import com.vir.service.iTranslateProcessorService;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Api(tags = "iTranslate")
public class iTranslateController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("iTranslatorService")
    private iTranslateProcessorService itranslateProcessorService;


    @ApiOperation(value = "Translate a text input.")
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Generic error", response = ApiError.class)
    @PostMapping(value = "/iTranslate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public iTranslator iTranslate(@RequestBody(required = true) String text, @RequestBody(required = true) String target) {
        return itranslateProcessorService.process(text, target);
    }
}
```

I also made the ItranslateProcessorService interface, which will call the iTranslator model. My question is, where do I make the call to the google API, in that model? How do I make it so that it returns the translation or json file the google API returns?  [Here is the documentation of the google API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries)

Any pointing in the right direction would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously an HTTP request that you'll send. Your interface implementation will make an HTTP connection, POST the request, and return the response.

Be sure to pool those HTTP connections.  They're expensive to create.

Make sure you think about what should happen if the Google Translate call times out or fails.

I disagree with your choice of return type: I'd recommend using the `ResponseEntity<T>` and make the generic type something that makes sense for your problem.

You need to know that the Google Translate service is *not* free. You have to pay if you intend to do more than a handful of translations over a period of time.

Comment: Thank you! Why should I use 'code'(ReponseEntity<T>)?
Also, any spring libaries I should look into for the interface implementation and handling if the google call times out or fails?

Comment: Returning the interface seems totally wrong to me.  What do you expect a client to do with that?  If you use ResponseEntity, Spring will take care of the translation to the MIME type specified by the user.  It'll translate your response object to XML or JSON depending on what the client wants.  The HTTP client should handle the timeout.  Your interface should throw exceptions if you want the controller to handle it and inform the caller.